# How to rebase in tortoisehg?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Often after committing changes, I do a pull, before pushing my changes, and someone has already committed changes. I could do another (merge) commit, but where possible I like to maintain linear history, as it makes things a bit easier to read.

So how does one rebase a changeset using tortoisehg, without resorting to using the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First enable rebase:

File -> Settings -> Extensions

[image]

Then (after restarting tortoisehg)

1. Update to the changeset you want to rebase on to.

[image: updating to base changeset]

2. Right click on change you want to rebase and select the Modify History -> Rebase menu.

[image: clicking rebase]

3. Click Rebase.

And you should end up with something like this:

[image]

Warnings:

1. It's not usually a good idea to rebase a changeset with a public Phase.
2. Avoid rebasing changes that are likely to produce complicated merge conflicts.