# How to copy working directory to a new commit

Tags: mercurial

I have the following commit structure:

```
a->b->c
```

Now c is an experiment, and it diverges significantly from b (to the point where any changes to b cause conflicts in c). I'd like to keep c, but want to stop maintaing the chain. Because there are so many conflicts between b and c, simple rebasing would be a bunch of work.

So I want to make

```
a->b
 \->c'
```

where `c'` is simply a copy of the workspace in `c`. In git I would use `git reset --soft a` and just make a new commit for my `c'`, is there something equivalent I can do in mercurial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use `revert --all`

pseudo commands (letters `a`,`c` mean revids of commits ):

1. `update -r a`
2. `revert --all -r c`
3. `commit -m "new c"`
4. `strip -r c`

a guide to using revert all using thg GUI can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61378294/361714)

Comment: This is what I would do to. Except that the final strip is optional and/or you might want to wait to do that until later, just as a backup. You can undo a strip too but that's a little harder.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm going to post what I ended up doing, but hope I get a better answer.

1. Make a "do nothing" commit on a (in my case, I added a line). We need the fake because rebasing onto `a` from `b` will stop saying `nothing to rebase`.

```
a->b->c
\->f
```

2. `hg rebase -s b -d f --keep` clones the whole branch:

```
a->b->c
\->f->b'->c'
```

3. `hg histedit`, fold c' and drop f.

```
a->b->c
\->c''
```

4. `hg prune c`

```
a->b
\->c''
```