# Update multiple commit messages in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, phabricator

I submitted two revisions ([1](https://phabricator.services.mozilla.com/D82507), [2](https://phabricator.services.mozilla.com/D82508)) for Review in Mozilla's Phabricator instance. I was asked to amend the commit message for both the revisions. I did search for previous questions on this topic, like [this one,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8182858/mercurial-how-to-amend-the-last-commit) but most of them work for amending a single (the most recent) commit.

I used TortoiseHG Workbench and used the "Commit" button and was able to amend the commit message for the latest (most recent) commit, which is marked as `default`/`tip`. But when I try the same procedure for the second revision, it just brings up the first revision again -

[image]

How do I amend the commit message for the other revision (marked red in the screenshot) as well? Additionally, how do I push both changes to Phabricator again, without creating new revisions? The last time I executed `moz-phab`, it created two entirely new revisions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Amend only changes the parent commit, and additionally it only works if the commit has no child revs.

You can use Amend to do this, but it requires a couple of [rebases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57421627/361714).

(*assuming you have no uncommitted changes*)

1. First update to 538966
2. Right click on 538995 -> Modify History -> Rebase.
3. Update to 538952
4. Use Amend.
5. Right click on 538995 -> Modify History -> Rebase.
6. Use Amend to change (538995) if you haven't alreayd.

Comment: 1. Commits **already pushed** 2. Even if Phabricator is non-publishing server (thus modify pushed csets is allowed), new push will create new head