# Updating local repo with changes from remote repo in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, rebase, revert

My company uses Mercurial 3.6.3 (I know it is very old, but I have no say in this). After cloning the remote repo, I made a couple of local commits using `hg commit`. After some time, I wanted to fetch the latest commits from the remote repo and rebase my commits on top of them. I ran `hg pull -u`, and for some reason the remote commits were applied on top of my local commits.

What do I do so that my two local commits are placed at the top instead of squished in between commits from the remote repo?

Answer (score 0):

`rebase` (which you have already tagged in your question). ([how to rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57421627/361714))

Of course you local commits must be, not pushed, so either draft or secret phase, which they very likely are.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the remote changesets were placed on top of your local changesets unless there's something we haven't been told. What evidence have you got for that? For the sake of argument, if the assertion were true, we'd have to conclude that either you had inadvertently pushed prior to the pull, or that the repo is corrupt.

Please post glog output of relevant changesets. If the repo might be corrupt, test it with "hg verify".

Comment: I fully agree with what is said here, although it possibly should have been a comment and not an "answer".